# Rotating a 4th-dimension Array of symbolic variables

Tags: matrix, tensors, rotation

I am looking to rotate a 4th dimension array C[i,j,k,l] using a rotation matrix Q[i,j]. I already know how this is done in 3x3 matrices (Q.A.Transpose[Q]) but I am having a hard time doing it for a 3x3x3x3 matrix.

A mathematically correct expression would be

[image]

which is basically nested `Sum`s, but I don't know how to code this in Mathematica.

Comment: I like the answer by Brent the most. If I needed the best possible performance, I would try the one by WReach.

Comment: Thanks Szabolcs, I will take a look at that post and come back if I have any questions.